# Интерпретация класса в визуальную часть

Tags: c#, winforms

В любом проекте существуют классы и в определенный момент их данные необходимо отображать на формах (визуальная часть для класса).

В случае если класс один, вроде не сложное дело:
*можно свойства класса ассоциировать с визуальными компонентами формы. У класса реализовать интерфейс с событием изменения свойства (PropertyChanged). Ну и выполнить привязку к свойствам класса - значения визуальных компонентов формы.*

В случае если классов много (массив): *как отобразить на форме их в виде таблицы, с возможностью нормальной ассоциации выбранной строки и класса ? Делал к примеру List - в случае с простым классом все было нормально отображал его в DataGridView через BindingSource и всегда через BindingSource.Current получал класс выбранной строки. Но как только начал добавлять сложные свойства в него типа Nullable<> и т.п. DataGridView почему-то отказался отображать список вообще.*

Суть вопроса не в моих описанных манипуляциях (описание лишь для понимания вопроса), а в следующем: как лучше всего ассоциировать и отображать классы с их визуальным отображением на WindowsForms, с наименьшим написанием кода обработок преобразований и т.п.. Так же учесть что бывают массивы классов которые надо отображать в виде таблиц.
Поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 2):

*В любом проекте существуют классы и в определенный момент их данные необходимо отображать на формах (визуальная часть для класса).*

Вот в этом состоит ваша главная ошибка. Не надо делать "толстые" классы, разбейте свое приложение на слои, и каждому слою пусть соответствует свой класс, свой для интерфейса, свой для модели, для слоя данных тоже свой. Тогда каждый из этих классов будет достаточно прост и не будет необходимости пихать в каждый из них всю логику приложения. `Winforms` для меня несколько незнакомая штука, но ЕМНИП поддерживает шаблон [`MVP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter), с которым стоит ознакомится, и писать классы исходя из этого шаблона.

Comment: Классы которые отображаю на формах - в них только свойства.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, если в классах которые вы используете в интерфейсе, только свойства, то откуда у вас возникают проблемы с их отображением?

Comment: возникает проблема с отображением массива классов в виде таблицы.
К примеру класс "Book" отображаем на форме "BookForm".
А есть класс "BookPage" их много в каждом классе "Book".
И например на форме "BookForm" мы хотим отобразить табличку со списокм его "BookPage". Как сие сотворить в удобном виде ?
А когда на форме BookForm мы в списке 2 раза кликнем на конкретную запись, откроется форма BookPageForm для просмотра конкретного класса BookPage

Comment: @IvanZakirov чтобы отобразить табличку используйте датагрид контрол. Или мне просто не понятно в чем проблема у вас.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, у вас же получалось это сделать через `List<Book>`? В принципе, у вас должен быть класс, заточенный именно на отображение, возникают проблемы с `Nullable type`, убрать `Nullable` и поставить значение по умолчанию. Всю логику из класса уберите в слой ниже. И т. д. и т. п.

Comment: Через List<Book> получалось, возможно и вправду  нужно убрать сложные типы Nullable. Но к примеру возникают переменные хранящие дату. Дата не может быть Null - соответственно придется прибегать к различному множеству условных обработок и т.п...

Comment: @IvanZakirov, разбейте логику этого класса на логику представления и логику модели. Вместо `Book` содержаший связи на `BookPage` сделайте простые `BookView` и `BookPageView` без всяких связей и только для отображение. Потом создайте создайте класс `BookModel` в котором будет, например, метод `PagesGet()` который будет возвращать вам коллекцию `BookPage`. Что касается обработок даты и тп. снисите их по слоям ниже, а собственно в классе отображения им не место.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, да надо добавить `BookModel` и `BookPageModel` будут  возвращать, например через свойства, соответсвенно `BookView` и `BookPageView`. Ну это так, очень приблизительная структура.